# MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. Asp.netCore application on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have developed an application in asp.net core EF, with MySql DB. Application is deployed on Google Cloud App Engine. I am trying Connecting Google Cloud App Engine application to Cloud MySql under same cloud project.  Locally i am able to connect this database, but when deployed on google cloud i am getting error

**MySqlException: Timeout expired.** The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)

```
MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.**
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
```

I am using below connecting string

```
 "DefaultConnection": "host=33.444.**.**;port=3306;database=mYdb;user=root;password=pASS"
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzqNW.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "Connecting from App Engine" page [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#connecting_the_flexible_environment_to) on the Cloud SQL docs. You need to enable the Cloud SQL server in your app.yaml, and then connect via `127.0.0.1:5432`.